# Adding an exception to choose between two code blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How would I choose between two blocks:

```
page.parser.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "realviewLink", " " ))]').each do |product|

page.parser.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "gbb-productTitle", " " ))]').each do |product|
```

I tried adding a begin/recuse and if/else and kept getting unexpected keyword errors. How do i choose the second statement if the first statement = [] ?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the easier way to do it would be:

```
first_xpath_expr = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "realviewLink", " " ))]'
second_xpath_expr = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "gbb-productTitle", " " ))]'
xpath_result = page.parser.xpath(first_xpath_expr).map { |product| process_first_xpath_expr(product) }
if xpath_result.blank?
  xpath_result = page.parser.xpath(second_xpath_expr).map { |product| process_second_xpath_expr(product) }
end
```